# Comparing JSON with possible differences - how to do this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, puppeteer

### Summary - CRON JOB every 10 minutes

My app scrapes data from a site and retrieves JSON in the following format:

```
[{
    price: '$12,500',
    title: '2003 Jeep Wrangler X Sport Utility 2D',
    location: 'Valrico, Florida',
    miles: '90K miles',
    imgUrl: 'https://scontent-mia3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c43.0.260.260a/p261x260/95585818_10158483215408453_5232171551314411520_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=843cd7&_nc_oc=AQnRkSY39Su7LJ3YcapqFxNeys_RLB964OEHIjAMP6T3PwHB2dhHyKL9Y8xLapOUpns&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-2.xx&oh=48828c46faf75c08d28b656459caaf01&oe=5ED8EA6F',
    itemURL: '/marketplace/item/525451485002934/'
  },
  {
    price: '$15,500',
    title: '2012 Jeep Wrangler Unlimited Sport SUV 4D',
    location: 'Clearwater, Florida',
    miles: '95K miles',
    imgUrl: 'https://scontent-mia3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c63.0.260.260a/p261x260/92586992_10156757268737397_3495264851003965440_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=843cd7&_nc_oc=AQk_rGSLpKWlkQrYAfXAZXCuV2iZ2cdmVi2lwvjhABGFbFycuawGBR4O-ax3VqUIBX4&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-1.xx&oh=af5d06bf5564aa9d062ed4427ed1873e&oe=5ED72FA5',
    itemURL: '/marketplace/item/2901350359949722/'
  }
]
```

This information is saved to a file **newjeeps.json**

The front end uses this data to display on the site.

### BUT...

I only want NEW items to display on the page. Meaning, each time the script is run, I want to show items that weren't already shown.

So I figured I would compare the two results, and save the difference to newjeeps.json , so the web page would always show the new items. Right?

I AM ONLY COMPARING THE TITLE.  IF THE TITLEs MATCH, REMOVE FROM FINAL ARRAY. ( yeah, in a perfect world... )

Well here is my code. It does not error, but it also does not save the differing items. I want to remove duplicates, and re-save the new data.

```
const initScraper = async () => {

  // Get currently listed items on Marketplace
  const items = await getItems('Jeep Wrangler');
  console.log(items);

  // Get OLD Jeeps
  const existingResults = jsonfile.readFileSync(fileName);
  const ex = existingResults.length;

    var existingTitle;
    var newTitle;
    var newItems = [];

    /* Loop through EXISTING (newjeeps.json) */
    for (var i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
      /* Existing Title */
      existingTitle = existingResults[i].itemTitle;
      /* Loop through NEW data */
      for (y = 0; y < items.length; y++) {
        /* New Title */
        newTitle = items[y].itemTitle;
        /* Do we have a match? */
        if (existingTitle == newTitle) {

          //console.log("match");
          // Remove from new results
          items.splice(y, 1);

          // Change detected?
          changed = true;

        }
      }
    }

  if (changed) {
    const page2 = await browser.newPage();
    await page2.goto(`http://john.mail.com/mail.php`);
      jsonfile.writeFile(fileName, items, function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  })
  }



  console.log("done");

}
```

Does anyone see what's going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: At the loop, should `ex.length` be `ex` instead? You already set the length to `ex`.

Comment: I change it. I am still getting this:  (node:11848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Ok, but with that one removed, length is in 2 other places, know which one? (maybe at items, but I don't know)

Comment: Ok now I am getting no error, but no differences being written to the file.  Here is the latest code, including sample data:  https://gist.github.com/johnsdeveloper/68fbab6f32c9acdc0afa38a08b739706

Comment: Did your problem get solved??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause to this problem is that you are trying to access a attribute `itemTitle`  which is not present within the object.

```
    newTitle = items[y].itemTitle;
```

This should be corrected as follows.

```
    newTitle = items[y].title;
```